# Not able to fire angular function (John Papa style)

Tags: angularjs

Here's the `form` in `html`:

```
<form ng-submit="vm.setTest(test)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" required />in USD
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here's the `JavaScript`:

```
var vm = this;
vm.setTest = setTest;
function setTest(test) {
    alert(test);
}
```

Please note, that no `$scope` involved and should not be.

Comment: You would need to do `vm.setTest = setTest` as well, and then use `vm.setTest` in the template

Comment: It actually is, forgot to edit. Thank you for showing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out. This is how now `html` looks:

```
<form ng-submit="testController.setTest(test)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" required />in USD
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to declare setTest like this

```
vm.setTest(test) {
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: `[js] ';' expected.` is what I receive when I do that.